# Prevent fallback font showing when loading google fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts

In my `<head>` I have:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

with the CSS:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
}
```

Annoyingly if I load without cache it always flashes to cursive first even though `display=swap` is supposed to stop this.

I have also tried adding:

```
html.wf-loading * {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

But I don't think that is even set. The only way I have managed to prevent any flashing is by doing this:

```
<body id="body" style="display: none;" onload="document.querySelector('#body').style.display = '';">
```

Which is not what I want.

---

Example when holding `cmd-shift-R` (forcing no cache):
[image]